# Python: run code on enter and exit grab?

Tags: python, 3d-view

Is there a way that I can run one operator when the user enters grab mode (G) in the 3D view and another operator when the user exits (Enter/ESC)?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is "grab mode" ?

Comment: I updated to be more clear